# How to get Pivot table without specifing inner sql columns in outer brackets in PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Currently i am using `PostgreSQL Plus Advance Server 9.3` and i have a table like :-

```
   Section    Status    ct
    A          Active    1
    A          Inactive  2
    B          Active    4
    B          Inactive  5
```

And i am getting below pivot table using following below query:-

```
      SELECT * FROM crosstab(
               'SELECT section, status, ct
                FROM   t
                ORDER  BY 1,2',$$VALUES ('Active'), ('Inactive')$$) 
        AS ct ("Section" text, "Active" int, "Inactive" int);

        Section    Active    Inactive
        A          1         2
        B          4         5
```

so my question is that is it possible to get the same output without specifying input sql query column name(i.e. `"Section" text`) in `ct()`. Thanks.

I means i want the same output using query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
           'SELECT section, status, ct
            FROM   t
            ORDER  BY 1,2',$$VALUES ('Active'), ('Inactive')$$) 
    AS ct ("Active" int, "Inactive" int);
```

Comment: In the second example you've asked for two columns from the crosstab rather than three - I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Richard I am trying to say that i want all the columns of "select statement" and "$$values statement$$" i.e. "section,Active,Inactive" by only writing the "$$values$$" column name in ct() like ct("Active" int, "Inactive" int)like happens in sql server pivot query

Comment: Ah, you are trying to let the "inner" column-name show through? No, I don't think there is a way to do that without wrapping the crosstab call in another function.

Comment: @Richard thanks for quick response, your means there is no way to do that.